Time evolution operator for hamiltonian to find evolved wavefunction at different time step
I have a wavefunction which is the eigenvector of the smallest eigenvalue.
\[Psi]0 = gseigvec 

\[Psi]0 = {-0.0495351 - 0.289625 I, 0.371609 - 0.524948 I, 0.633961 - 0.108427 I, 0.239823 + 0.169769 I}

Dimension of the hamiltonian is given by dim = Length[H];
\[Psi] = Table[\[Psi]i[t], {i, dim}];

This code constructs the different components of psi whose dimension is same as dim.
Differential equation to be solved -
eqns = Table[-I D[\[Psi][[i]], t] == 
    Sum[H[[i, j]] \[Psi][[j]], {j, dim}], {i, dim}];

Initial conditions -
initialConditions = Table[\[Psi][[i]][0] == \[Psi]0[[i]], {i, dim}];

Using NDSolveValue to obtain a list of time-evolved wavefunctions at different time-steps up to T = 10 and deltaT = 0.001.
sol = NDSolveValue[Join[eqns, initialConditions], \[Psi], {t, 0, T}];

This gives me the error of The function [Psi]i[t] appears as the head of the expression \ [Psi]i[t][0].
Could somebody please tell me how these errors can be fixed? I am not very experienced in Mathematica. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
For testing this code, I am adding the hamiltonian matrix H and the dimension of H in this case is 4.
    H = {
   {1.5 + 0. I, -1.73205 + 0. I, 0 + 0. I, 0 + 0. I},
   {-1.73205 + 0. I, 0.5 + 0. I, -2. + 0. I, 0 + 0. I},
   {0 + 0. I, -2. + 0. I, 0.5 + 0. I, -1.73205 + 0. I},
   {0 + 0. I, 0 + 0. I, -1.73205 + 0. I, 1.5 + 0. I}
};

Ultimately, I want to use the evolved psi_t at each time step to find <psi(t)|N1-N2|psi(t)>/N as a function of time.
Where N is the total number of particles which is 3 in this example.
Code for this expectation value -
expectationValue = 
  Table[Re[Conjugate[\[Psi][t]] . (N1 - N2) . \[Psi][t]], {t, 0, T, 
    deltaT}];

and N1 and N2 are 4 by 4 matrices
N1 = DiagonalMatrix[{0,1,2,3}]
N2 = DiagonalMatrix[{3,2,1,0}]

Plotting this quantity -
ListLinePlot[expectationValue, PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Time (t)", "<N1 - N2>"}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Expectation Value of N1 - N2"]


You  will make progress faster if you read about syntax. There are some introductions (https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/  ,  https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=362&v=1220).  For starters \[Psi]0 is not the same as psi0.  H is undefined

The fact that you got the error D: 1 is not a valid variable means that you tried to take the derivative of something with respect to 1, which obviously doesn't make sense. You've probably previously defined t to have the value 1 (t = 1). Evaluate Clear[t] and try again.

@march, yes it works now. However, I am still getting this error -
The function [Psi]i[t] appears as the head of the expression 
[Psi]i[t][0]
when I run the code for sol

@CraigCarter, H is defined in my code. Here in this post, I added only it's non-zero matrix elements. Please check (1,1) = 1.5, (1,2) = -1.73205, etc.

There  are still  many syntax errors in your code,  (1,2) = 1.5 is not valid syntax as you will see if you evaluate it.  I’m still not seeing anything like ‘H=‘ … in your post. I strongly recommend that you look at some  introductory  material on the language.

@CraigCarter, I added it now. Initially, I did not add it because when I tried copying from mathematica, it was not of the form that I just added now. So, I simply added manually non-zero matrix elements - therefore, it is not part of the code, only for reference. Now I updated it correctly. May I know which syntax error are you referring to other than H?

1/2 One of the things you can do when troubleshooting code is make sure that every step is doing what you expect it to.  Rather than running the whole code, check things step by step. For instance, the error that you've run into ("The function [Psi]i[t] appears as the head of the expression \ [Psi]i[t][0] when I run the code for sol") mean that there's some problem with the definitions of \[Psi]i and friends. So evaluate \[Psi] = Table[\[Psi]i[t], {i, dim}] and see if it actually gives you what you expected. (It doesn't.)...

2/2 ...Also,\[Psi]0 is not the same as psi0, pointed out earlier. You haven't specified a value for T, yet you're using NDSolve. You're doing [Psi]i[t][0] instead of [Psi][i][0] (so you should be doing \[Psi]i[t] /. t->0, or something of the sort, in the definition of the initial conditions. You haven't specified whats N1 and N2 are, etc. You haven't replaced \[psi]i[t] with the solutions spit out by NDSolve, so it won't plot anything. Please try an easier problem first, going through the documentation to ensure you have the right syntax, to see examples, etc.

@march I highlighted the defns of N1, N2, T and deltaT into the code part. Okay, I will check for mistakes in my code.

Here is how I would code this up.  For the initial data, we have
H = {{1.5 + 0. I, -1.73205 + 0. I, 0 + 0. I, 0 + 0. I},
     {-1.73205 + 0. I, 0.5 + 0. I, -2. + 0. I, 0 + 0. I},
     {0 + 0. I, -2. + 0. I, 0.5 + 0. I, -1.73205 + 0. I},
     {0 + 0. I, 0 + 0. I, -1.73205 + 0. I, 1.5 + 0. I}};
dim = Length[H];
psi0 = {-0.0495351 - 0.289625 I, 0.371609 - 0.524948 I, 0.633961 - 0.108427 I, 0.239823 + 0.169769 I}l;

The, to generate the equations, we do
psis = Table[psi[i][t], {i, dim}];
eqns = Join[
         Table[-I D[psis[[i]], t] == Sum[H[[i, j]] psis[[j]], {j, dim}], {i, dim}],
         Table[psis[[i]] == psi0[[i]] /. t -> 0, {i, dim}]
        ];

Solving the equation, we get
sol = NDSolveValue[eqns, psis, {t, 0, 50}];

Finally, we plot the expectation value of
N1 = DiagonalMatrix[{0, 1, 2, 3}];
N2 = DiagonalMatrix[{3, 2, 1, 0}];

to get
Plot[Re[Conjugate[sol].(N1 - N2).sol], {t, 0, 50}]



Notice a couple of things about the code. Evaluating
\[Psi] = Table[\[Psi]i[t], {i, dim}]

yields
(* {\[Psi]i[t], \[Psi]i[t], \[Psi]i[t], \[Psi]i[t]} *)

Of course, i hasn't been replaced, because Mathematica sees \[Psi]i has one symbol, and it can't separate the symbol into its components. So, we use \[Psi][i] instead, which allows Mathematica to understand that it needs to put the numerical value of the index i in that place to create four differently-labeled functions. (I have used just psi in the code above to avoid having to continue typing "Esc - psi - Esc".)
Secondly,
initialConditions = Table[\[Psi][[i]][0] == \[Psi]0[[i]], {i, dim}];

doesn't work, because it just appends a [0] to the expression in \[Psi][[i]]. For instance, if \[Psi][[1]] = \[Psi][1][t], \[Psi][[i]][0] evaluates to
\[Psi][1][t][0]

Mathematica has no way of knowing that you wanted to replace t with 0, so you need to tell Mathematica to make this replacement. To do this, I used a replacement rule, i.e.,
Table[psis[[i]] == psi0[[i]] /. t -> 0, {i, dim}];

e.g., psis[[1]] == psi0[[1]] /. t -> 0 evaluates to
psi[1][0] == -0.0495351 - 0.289625 I

Finally, there are two issues with
Table[Re[Conjugate[\[Psi][t]] . (N1 - N2) . \[Psi][t]], {t, 0, T, deltaT}]

one fundamental and one practical.  The first is that Mathematica has no way of knowing what you mean by \[Psi][t], because you assigned the output of NDSolveValue to sol, not to \[Psi][t] (which might cause a recursion error anyway). Thus, you need to use sol to plot this expectation value. The second issue is that you can just Plot the output functions of NDSolveValue, because they are InterpolatingFunctions that can be plotted for every value of t in between 0 and T. Thus, we do instead
Plot[Re[Conjugate[sol].(N1 - N2).sol], {t, 0, 50}]

